# Django rest framework bulk post object

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want insert bulk json via django rest_framework however, I get a error message ;

typed following line ;

```
{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got list."
    ]
}
```

my serializer.py file include following code block;

```
class DrfSerializerV2(serializers.ModelSerializer):
def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    many=kwargs.pop('many',True)
    super(DrfSerializerV2,self).__init__(many=True,*args,**kwargs)
class Meta:
    model = DrfData
    fields=['id','name','duration','rating','typ']
```

and my views.py file ;

```
class ActionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
 queryset = DrfData.objects.filter(typ="action")
 serializer_class = serializers.DrfSerializerV2
```

finally send json file via post;

```
[
    {"name":"m1","duration":120,"rating":4.7},
    {"name":"m2","duration":120,"rating":4.5}
]
```

however, I can't handle this error message.
if I send sperataly, there is no problem.

but, I can't resolve this error for bulk insert

Comment: this is invalid JSON, it should have double quotes

Comment: I have tried with double quotes but I get same error message. [
   {
      "name":"m1",
      "duration":120,
      "rating":4.7
   },
   {
      "name":"m2",
      "duration":120,
      "rating":4.5
   }
]